# Can I get my recruit back after he has turned red?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Playing Assassin's Creed 3 and one of my recruits just turned red. Is he dead? Is there any way to get him back or replaced by a new one?

Is there only so many recruits in the game I can get, and if they're dead, that's it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 6 recruits, and unlike previous games, they are unique and can't be changed. When a recruit is "injured" during a fight alongside Connor, or takes part of a failed mission, they will become red, and won't be able to come to Connor's aid in fights or go on mission, for a **limited amount of time**, after which, they will "heal" and return to normal.

They can't die, and will forever be with you. Also, losing a recruit to injury doesn't seem to have any implications on the recruit, so you will get them back just as you left them. Just wait a while, and you will get them back, all healed up and ready to kick some Templar a**.

Comment: Ah, that's a relief. Do you know how long they are gone? Or does it vary?

Comment: Don't remember exactly, but I would guess that it was around 10-15 minutes of gameplay.